# Run Many thread over single context class in EF

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework, thread-safety, task

I have some long time taking process(to Get data from Db like Country List, Business List (around 1500 rows)). So I created a separate method to get those data.

But It is saying

> The context cannot be used while the model is being created. This
>   exception may be thrown if the context is used inside the
>   OnModelCreating method or if the same context instance is accessed by
>   multiple threads concurrently. Note that instance members of DbContext
>   and related classes are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

```
private IList<Business> GetBusiness(IRepositories repos, IImageStore store)
{
    var data = repos.BusinessRepo.GetAll();
    //Some more calculation on the basis of Data.
    return data;
}

**similar function for country**
```

Now I'm calling those method from main

```
Task<List<Business>>[] taskBusiness = new Task<List<Business>>[1];
 taskBusiness[0] = Task.Run(() => GetBusiness(repos, imageStore));

 Task<List<Country>>[] taskCountry = new Task<List<Country>>[1];
 taskCountry[0] = Task.Run(() => GetCountry(repos, imageStore));

 //Some More calculation
 .
 .
 // before method end
 Task.WaitAll(taskBusiness);
 Task.WaitAll(taskCountry);
 var business = taskBusiness[0].Result;
 var country = taskCountry[0].Result;
```

Comment: Are you using the same context instance in different calls at the same time?

Comment: @DavidG:yes. I'm not initializing it again

Comment: *Why* are you trying to use the same context from multiple threads? There is no benefit to this, although there *are* significant downsides

Comment: BTW 1500 rows is a **very** small number of rows. Retrieving them shouldn't even be noticeable. Either something is very wrong with the GetBusiness, GetCountry functions, there are no indexes or both. Using a single context *can* cause such issues as it's essentially a single connection and any locks acquired, will remain until the connection is closed. You could block your application with less than a dozen such connections

Comment: And what is the question? As the error message tells you this is not allowed. Don't do that and the error goes away.

Answer (score 1):

The `DbContext` class is not thread safe (your error message pretty much tells you that) so you should never use the same instance in multiple threads. Instead, you should create a different object for every simultaneous call.

From the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx) on `DbContext` (emphasis mine):

> *Thread Safety*: Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. **Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.**

Comment: one more thing I need to access session inside GetBusiness Method .
`System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserCountry"] = getCountryName;` But When I debug , Then it's saying `Current is null`

Comment: That's a different question, but I suggest passing that in as a parameter to  `GetBusiness`.